# Install and especific checkout version of bundle symfony2

Tags: symfony, bundle, composer-php

I would like to install and especific checkout version of a bundle in my project. When I was developing the checkout version of the bundle I was using was dev-master 5677b63, but then, I updated using composer and I got installed the newest version, which has a small piece of code that kind of destroys everything (it was an issue that they solved). I was wondering if I could tell composer to install the old checkout of dev:master and not the latest one. Is that even possible?

Comment: You should fix your code and not depend on any master branch!

Comment: Don't commit the generated `composer.lock` file if after the update your tests fail and you need to go back. Going forward instead and fix the issue in your code is the real solution, though. At some point in the future you have to update, and then you'll have to fix it anyway.

Comment: Actually that's what I did, I fixed my code, i agree with you it is the real solution. But I was also afraid for other updates... what if I update without noticing and everything starts failing? Can I force the specific checkout in the composer so everything remains the same? (and because I am extremely lazy too... luckily the fix for my part was just one line (:  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it could be done with something like this:

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        "foo/bar": "dev-master#1333333333333333333333333333333333333337"
    }
    ...
}
```

Obviously, you would need to replace `1333333333333333333333333333333333333337` with commit ID...

Source: https://coderwall.com/p/ub4ejg

Comment: Yes, even though I already fix my code, I tried that and it works perfectly, it gets the specific checkout!.